# Keeping index when using pandas read_csv in chunks

Tags: python, pandas, memory

I ran into a MemoryError issue with Python 3.4.0 I am attempting to resolve using techniques I have came across here. When using read_csv in pandas, I am currently using the `iterator = True`, `chunksize = 1000` technique that eventually uses concat with `ignore_index = True` as well. The index to my data is important however in this case, and is not preferred to be just numbered 0 to n-1. When deleting the `ignore_index` out of my concat statement, the file again receives a MemoryError. I am wondering if there is anyway to either reproduce the index to match the new numbered index that won't produce a memory error, or a better solution to avoid the MemoryError while keeping the index_col. Below is the code I am attempting to run, which successfully runs but again changes the index from 'Player' to numbers 0 to n-1.

```
tp = pd.read_csv(filename, header=0, index_col = 'Player', iterator = True, chunksize = 1000) # use first column as index
df = pd.concat(tp, ignore_index = True)
```

Thank you all and if any more info is needed please let me know. My apologies for the slightly amateur question, I am rather new to Python.

Comment: what happens when you change the chunksize?

Comment: @MattR I lowered the chunksize to 100 and deleted the ignore_index and came across the same issue of a MemoryError

Comment: Have you tried anything with [`set_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)? you can create a new index once the dataframe is read (I'm just asking some questions in order to filter out possible solutions)

Comment: @MattR I have not used set_index(), but should that be done with the read_csv line in place of index_col or concat in place of ignore_index?

Comment: @MattR I'm afraid if I use set_index it will do the same thing as my index_col in the read_csv statement right? Thus again be overwritten in the ignore_index.

Comment: I think this question needs more detail. What is it that you are trying to accomplish? Are you trying to add data from a large file into a single dataframe?

Comment: @MattR sorry for the vagueness, still learning the ropes in how to ask questions. I have since tried an outer set_index but to no avail as a MemoryError still occurred. The main objective here is to append multiple CSVs together with different columns but similar rows, where they are binded by the column 'Player.'